# What is "mud-jacked", and why is it not done in the UK?

Tags: concrete

I have seen of few questions/answers about "mud-jacked", but I have never come across it in the uk.

Comment: From what I've read I think it's injecting mud under concrete to lift/level the surface, but a definitive answer would be useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Mudjacking is the process of pumping a water, dirt and cement mixture
>   under a concrete slab in order to lift it.

[Source](http://www.wisegeek.com/what-is-mudjacking.htm)

Comment: what do you mean by "dirt"?

Comment: dirty mixed in water = mud